# Perl script: combining the data from many files

Tags: matrix

There are many text files that consist

Comment: Your requirement is far from clear. Is that the the *whole* of file `701`? You need to explain it without the bioinformatics lingo. Explain how you would do it manually.

Comment: @user3084832 think we're almost there. Does uniqueclasses also contain the kingdom and phylum for the classes? Are you trying to send this info to the console or a document?

Comment: @user3084832 try my update, hope its what you're looking for.

Comment: @user3084832 It wouldn't create any file, you would need to redirect STDOUT. I can't remember how to do that in linux. But in windows it be by using the example I provided at the top of the script. If you redirect to .txt it might not keep the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative. The output is written to STDOUT and is formatted as you requested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#Array of file names (these should be read from a separate file or constructed in situ)
#my @files = (701, 702, 703, 704);

my $nfiles = 4; #number of files in your dir change as per your need
my $finit  = 701; #the index of the first file

#Temporary hash and hash reference
my %names;
my $hash_ref;

#Start printing output (here we use STDOUT)
printf STDOUT "classname:";

# loop through files
#foreach my $file_name (@files) {
for (my $i = 0; $i < $nfiles; $i++) { #new loop that uses file names generated in situ
    #generate index of input file
    my $file_name = $finit + $i;

    #Continue print index to output
    printf STDOUT " %s", $file_name;

    #generate actual file name
    $file_name = "$file_name" . ".txt";

    #create handle
    open my ($fh) , '<', $file_name or die $!;

    #read line record
    while (my $rec = <$fh>) {
        #remove trailing end of line
        chomp $rec;

        #remove leading white space
        $rec =~ s/^\s+//;

        #remove trailing white space
        $rec =~ s/\s+$//;

        #skip blank lines
        next unless $rec;

        #split contents of record
        my ($k,$p,$c,$seq_count) = split /;/, $rec;

        #generate kpc_name
        my $kpc_name= "$k;$p;$c;";

        #store
        $hash_ref->{$file_name}{$kpc_name} = $seq_count;
        $names{$kpc_name}++; #this is just for storing the kpc_names seen in the files
                             #if you have the names already available you don't need this.
    }

    #close current file handle
    close($fh);
}

#Add new line to output
printf STDOUT "\n";

#loop through kpc_names (sorted alphabetically)
foreach my $kpc_name (sort keys %names) {
    #Begin construction of output line
    my $line_out = $kpc_name;

    #loop through each file name
    foreach my $file_name (@files) {
        #sprint the count if the file has that kpc_name, 0 otherwise
        $line_out .= sprintf " %s,",
            exists $hash_ref->{$file_name}{$kpc_name} ?
                $hash_ref->{$file_name}{$kpc_name} : 0;
    }

    #Remove extra comma at end of line
    chop $line_out;

    #Print line to output file (here STDOUT)
    print STDOUT "$line_out\n";
}
```

Comment: @user3084832 What would you like to fix?

Comment: You can generate the file names in situ. I will put this alternative in the code above.

Comment: Yes $kpc_name holds string of the form 'bacteria; actinobacteria; actinobacteria;'

Comment: add 'my' in front of the variable $file_name. The other two variables are already declared with 'my'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you aren't running it from the same directory you can pass the directory as an argument, otherwise it will default to the same directory.

It also prints to command line as default, and can be redirected to a file of your choosing.

```
Ex. perl progname.pl > output.tsv



#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#find files for reading and put into an array

my $dir = shift || "./"; #You can pass argument with directory, or default to same directory as program

opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "Could not open directory: $!";

my @files;
my @classes;

while(readdir($dh)) {
    if (/70\d50\d_classes.txt/){
        push @files, $_;
    }
}

#find out the classes
open (my $fh, "<", $dir . 'uniqueclasses.txt') or die "Could not open file: $!";

while(<$fh>){
    chomp;
    next unless $_;
    my @line = split /;\s?/;
    push @classes, [join(" ", @line[0,1]), {'class' => $line[2], 'found' => 0}];
}

close $fh;


#go through files and read each line in, only caring about class and count
for my $file(@files){
    open (my $fh, "<", $dir . $file) or die "Could not open file: $!";
    while(<$fh>){
        chomp;
        next unless $_;
        my @line = split /\s/;
        for my $i(0 .. $#classes){
            if($classes[$i][1]->{'class'} eq $line[2]){
                my $key = substr($file, 0,6);
                $classes[$i][1]->{$key} = $line[3];
                $classes[$i][1]->{'found'} = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}

#Check through array for classes not found in any files
#put it all together for display
#columns
print "\t\t\t\t";

my @columns;
for my $i(0..$#files){
    print "\t", ($columns[$i] = substr($files[$i],0,6));
}

print "\n";

#rows
for my $row (@classes) {
    my %data = %{$row->[1]};
    next unless $data{'found'};
    print "\n", $row->[0] ,"\t", $data{'class'};
    for (@columns){
        if(defined($data{$_})){ #checks if field is there, if so, includes value, if not adds 0
            print "\t$data{$_}";
        }
        else {
            print "\t0";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about bio, you'd have to fix the columns/ groupings

Comment: @user3084832 give me a moment I'll work that out. The input data used for this is the same as you have provided. So its seperated on the ";". If thats not how the fields are separated, please provide that. This will output a csv to the directory the program is run in.

Comment: @user3084832 added a method to find the files you are looking for. Won't work once you start getting to 800+

Comment: @user3084832 here '@csv' is just an array that holds all the values until we use them. you can change it to any name you'd like just be sure change all instances of '@csv' and '$csv[*anyvar]'. Also you can change the commas to tabs if you'd prefer. I noticed you added a duplicate question to stackoverflow, if you update this question with the info from that one, we may be able to help a lot better.